# Model ID changes when passed to the HttpPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am refactoring MvcMusicStore code and I'm in the process of updating the StoreManagerController. I have changed the Edit actions to the following:

```
    //
    // GET: /StoreManager/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Toy toy = dbStore.Toys.Find(id);
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(dbStore.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", toy.CategoryId);
        ViewBag.BrandId = new SelectList(dbStore.Brands, "BrandId", "Name", toy.BrandId);
        return View(toy);
    }

    //
    // POST: /StoreManager/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Toy toy)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dbStore.Entry(toy).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbStore.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(dbStore.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", toy.CategoryId);
        ViewBag.BrandId = new SelectList(dbStore.Brands, "BrandId", "Name", toy.BrandId);
        return View(toy);
    }
```

While testing, when I click the `Edit` action, the view displays fine and setting a breakpoint in the `Edit(int id)` method shows that the `ToyId` is 1. However, after I make a change and click Save, the `Toy` object being passed through the method `ActionResult Edit(Toy toy)` has the incorrect `ToyId` equal to 0.

Where is this modification occurring, or is there a copy of `toy` being passed back from the view and it is not correctly copying across the ToyId?

**Update: Added Post of Edit View**

```
@model Store.Models.Toy

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Toy</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ToyId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandId, "Brand")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("BrandId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BrandId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PictureUrl)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PictureUrl)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PictureUrl)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Toy Class**

```
[Bind(Exclude = "ToyId")]
public class Toy
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ToyId { get; set; }

    // ... other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Can you post your "Edit" View?

Comment: ...And the class body of `Toy` - or at least the bit that declares the `ToyId` member

Comment: done - I've just been refactoring the mvcmusicstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of

```
[Bind(Exclude = "ToyId")]
```

So the ToyID property is literally being ignored in the bind operation and the hidden value is not being used.

You can simply remove this from the class so that `ToyId` gets correctly bound from the POST operation; or, you can manually bind it in the controller method by copying the `id` route value to the `Toy`'s `ToyId` property (or add a method parameter called `id` to have it bound automatically).

There are some potential issues with allowing binding of ID properties etc, however, and this other SO provides a window into this: [ASP.NET MVC - Alternative for [Bind(Exclude = "Id")]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631000/asp-net-mvc-alternative-for-bindexclude-id)

Comment: Seems this was a bug with mvcmusicstore: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/workitem/6648?PendingVoteId=6648

Comment: @Seth - well, you didn't have much a chance then :D