# ModelState isvalid return false when id / key = 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, required, modelstate

ModelState Isvalid is returning false when Primary Key is 0 on Creation.

In model:

```
[Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
```

In database:

[image]

database data:

[image]

In View:

[image]

Value is 0:
[image]

ModelState IsValid return false:

[image]

Any idea why is it invalid?

Comment: Use a separate view model.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633032/5394220 it applies for aspnet MVC but the idea is the same. Not sure how you could archive something like Bind(Exclude=..) in NetCore though.

Comment: Its already a view model, the [key] is in the model and the model defined in a view model, with another model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. Don't return a null value and instead return a new instance of Course

```
  public ViewResult AddCourse(int id)
  {
        var course = yourservice.GetById(id);

        if(customer == null)
        {
            course = new Course();
        }
        return View(course);
    }
 }
```