# Asp.net mvc: automatically generating validation!

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the class code check there is no DataAnnotation.

```
 public int Rotate { get; set; }
```

Here is the its use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Screen.Rotate)
```

Here its generating html, y its generating validation rules????

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="Screen.Rotate" id="Screen_Rotate" data-val-required="The Rotate field is required." data-val-number="The field Rotate must be a number." data-val="true">
```

Note: If i change int Rotate to string Rotate then it does not generate extra attributes for validations like data-val-required, data-val-number etc.

Comment: Have you tried using `int?` instead of `int` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried int? but still same html is generating

Comment: Are you sure? Yes, you'll get the number validation, but you should not be getting required with `int?` . Your problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.com/0gpwTGKz

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700172/unrequired-property-keeps-getting-data-val-required-attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-nullable scalar values such as `int` and `DateTime` are always considered as required. `string` isn't required since strings are nullable. As @Biff said, use `int?` for a non-required `int`.

Comment: Please don't create a brand new question covering the same problem as an existing question with no accepted answer. Please update the existing question instead.

Comment: coure06- that completed question just points back to this one