# Removing Required Attribute from Class but MVC3 still won't post the form without a value in the text box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, required, componentmodel

I have a class.  At one point, I had set the properties of the class to [Required] using System.ComponentModel....

Okay, then I realized this was not needed.  I have removed the required property but when I try to submit the form to an ActionResult the form does NOT post and still is trying to enforce the TextBoxFor(theModelProperty) to be populated.

I have deleted the "obj" folder, the "bin" folder, and also "Cleaned" the solutions.  Still NO resolution.

I don't want to do a stupid workaround, I would like to do things correctly.  Any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set property as `nullable`,
2. Turn off required attribute for value
       types (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700172/unrequired-property-keeps-getting-data-val-required-attribute/4845768#4845768))

Comment: Hey, thanks very much.  That worked perfectly.  Can you help me out with the following? :-) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815653/my-working-application-mvc3-razor-unexplainably-stopped-working-iis-7)

Answer (score 1):

If you have value type properties. Client validation will always generate required validations. If you don't want required validation for value types make them nullable.