# fieldID is required. Error when trying to add a new object via MVC3, ModelStat.IsValid false errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations, modelstate

I have this ViewModel:

```cs
    [Key]
    public long KlijentID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength50", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string ImePrezime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLength50", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string Adresa { get; set; }

    //Rest of the Class, not important for the question.
```

In the view i have:

```cs
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Klijenti"))
    {
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.KlijentID)

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImePrezime)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImePrezime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImePrezime)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Adresa)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Adresa)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Adresa)
     </div>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Spremi" /><p>
    }
```

When i use it to update an object from database the controller action works fine:

```cs
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) throw new ValidationException();
    var k=new Klijent();
    Mapper.Map(klijent, k);
    repo.SaveKlijent(k);
    TempData["msg"] = MyResources.Properties.Resources.SaveDone;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", page);
```

But when i try to add a new object, than the `ModelState.IsValid` fails saying that the KlijentID is required.
`ErrorMessage:"The KlijentID field is required."`

I have checked, it is set as 0 as it should be for a new object. What is the problem here?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to add this to my `Application_Start` in *Global.asax*

```cs
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

The result is i still get a validation error, just now it says:
`ErrorMessage: "A value is required."`

This is getting a bit strange, it just seems to want that value really bad. Ghosts in the machine?

Comment: maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4700172/576752

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i have tried to do it that way and i have described the result in the question: didn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is because there was no value in incoming data from form. Validation engine checks dictionary of values, and if it is not found, adds ModelState error. Value is equal to 0 because it is default value of int type.

To solve this thing, just add @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id) in your Create view.

Comment: I already have that in my Create View, sorry, i will add it to the question

Comment: Where is it? Inside form tag?

Comment: Also, how are you posting form?

Comment: Yes, it is inside form tag, i have updated the View data in the question.

Comment: Can you add breakpoint after ModelState.IsValid and navigate to list of values? there will be a collection of errors for each member of your model. Find one that is not empty and please post here=)

Comment: `ErrorMessage-"The KlijentID field is required."` This is the only error in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I set my Primary key to nullable type and everything worked like a charm.