# MVC 3 Checkbox Turn Off Validation Not Using RequiredAttribute

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been looking around stackoverflow for this answer. Can't seem to get anywhere with them. I have an entity which has 5 navigation properties to other entities. Example:

```
public class Computer : DbEntity
{
    public virtual Ram Ram { get; set; }
    public Guid RamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Hdd Hdd { get; set; }
    public Guid HddId { get; set; }

    // etc. etc. you get the picture

}
```

In order to build the View up, I made partial Create views for `Hdd` and `Ram` etc. and referenced them into the main view:

```
@model ComputerSite.ViewModels.ComputerViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Computer Details</legend>
        ... some fields ...
    </fieldset>

    Html.RenderPartial("Create", "Ram");

    Html.RenderPartial("Create", "Hdd");
}
```

And I tested this and it works, all the data gets posted back to the ViewModel and it can be saved in the database, so I know all of that works. The problem comes when, a `Computer` has no `Ram`. I want to be able to check a box to say this won't be included. And when the form is submitted to bypass the `Ram` validation.

There should be a very easy and simple way, I don't mind if it is a JavaScript function that goes and changes some `data-` attributes client side. I'm just not entirely sure where to start, custom attributes aren't the way forward with this. It seems way to much just to change some fields. I still want the fields validated if the check box isn't checked and the validation is in place for that, and that bit works, hence why I'm asking the question, I just need to be able to selectively turn off different parts of the form.

Oh, and as a side note, NON of my properties in any of my entity classes have the `[Required]` attribute!

Examples please if you do JavaScript. I'm 100% proficient with it yet.

Comment: Are you open to JS solutions only?

Comment: well I'm using jquery unobtrusive validation, so it would have to be something that would tie into that, I can't imagine I need to do anything server side. Just disable a few fields using JS, what is your suggestion?

Comment: I use http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ very often. It supports only simple validations on client-side, but it is very powerful for server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled the form parts that I didn't want validated using JQuery and that worked.

```
<script type="javascript">
    $(function () {
        function EnableControls() {
             $("#Computer_Cpu").removeAttr("disabled");
             $("#Computer_Motherboard").removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        function DisableControls() {
             $("#Computer_Cpu").attr("disabled", "disabled");
             $("#Computer_Motherboard").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        var disabled = true;
        $("#Enable_Controls_Checkbox").change(function () {
             if (disabled) {
                 EnableControls();
             } else {
                 DisableControls();
             }
        });

        DisableControls();
    })

</script>
```

As a run through, this script Disables all controls that I want, at load up. So the default is you can't edit them. There is a checkbox called `Enable_Controls_Checkbox` that when checked will enable said controls. `attr(obj, obj)` from my understanding adds/changes an attribute of the HTML Dom, and `removeAttr(obj)` as it says, removes an attribute.

There is probably a more elegant solution to this, but it works neither the less.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the foolproof validation project, it has more validation methods, including requiredif. http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

On the side not, there is a setting that you can turn off to disable implicit validation.  look at this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845768/1563373

Comment: I'm going to try down the route of Nullable properties, cause that is what they can be.