# MVC 4 Validation Date ISSUE - Cannot blank out a previously entered date field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a model in MVC 4 that has a date field in it that is **not required** (NOTE: it is a nullable datetime field).

I can create an item with my view without a problem.

If I set the date field within the form and go back to edit it, I am unable to clear the date field because now all of a sudden the field has become required and I can't get passed validation.

Is there a way around this? I just want to blank out a previously entered date field.

Comment: Please show us the code of your model, controller and view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

Needed to add to Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
   .....
}
```

see:
[Unrequired property keeps getting data-val-required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700172/unrequired-property-keeps-getting-data-val-required-attribute)