# ASP.NET MVC. Non required fields are required in validations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, ef-code-first

I do have a POCO Class with some non required fields:

```
class MyClass{

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "1st interval")]
    public TimeSpan t1{ get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "2nd interval")]
    public TimeSpan t2 { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "3rd interval")]
    public TimeSpan t3 { get; set; }
}
```

but whenever I set the `[Required]` annotation or not. the validations fails.
I always got the "2nd interval is required" message on my view.

I'm using **only** Server validation.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Make the properties nullable - `public TimeSpan? t2 { get; set; }`

Comment: There are 2 ways: using nullable properties or use `[Bind(Exclude)]`. Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142990/the-id-field-is-required-validation-message-on-create-id-not-set-to-required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TimeSpan` is not nullable by default

Use Nullable;

```
public Nullable<TimeSpan> t2 { get; set; }
```

or

```
public TimeSpan? t2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: is it equivalent to public TimeSpan? t2 {get;set;} ?