# ASP.NET MVC - Make a property required, but not from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I have an MVC model that (grossly simplified) looks like this;

```
public class Person
{

    [Required]
    public string SpecialSauce { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

However, only the `Name` comes from the view. The `SpecialSauce` is provided server side.

```
person.SpecialSauce = "Ketchup"; //Hard-coded for example
```

However, before I save, I check `ModelState.IsValid`, which returns false, with the error "The SpecialSauce field is required."

How do I make the ModelState valid when the required model property is provided server side? I could remove the `[Required]` data annotation, but I want the EF database column to be non-nullable.

Comment: use viewmodel instead of your db class and dont add required attribute this time sauce property.

Comment: So I need a seperate model for the view? This is very basic, and would seem a shame to require a seperate model, but if thats the standard practice...

Comment: Remove `[Required]` attribute from the model but configure db mapping using [EF Fluent API](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx). Also it would be better to create a viemodel to separate concerns.

Comment: you are need to second resolution at that time or you can write your validate attribute and control it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a

Comment: or exclude it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142990/the-id-field-is-required-validation-message-on-create-id-not-set-to-required

Comment: If `person.SpecialSauce` is set only in the `HttpPost` why can't it be set in the `HttpGet` method and then return the `person` object to the view?

Comment: This is one of the (many) reasons for ViewModels. Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to ease the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, not quite sure how you expect `SpecialSauce` to be **required** but yet not allow the user to enter a value for `SpecialSauce` on the form and then you override it in the controller.

But.. here is an answer if `SpecialSauce` needs to be required.

Since you are setting `person.SpecialSauce` on the server side, you should set it in the `HttpGet` Method.  Then return the entire object back to the View.  If you don't want a user editing that field, then disable it via HTML or jQuery.

Here is an example:

**Controller**

```
// GET: ControllerName/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var myPerson = new Person()
    {
        SpecialSauce = "Ketchup"
    };

    return View(myPerson); // assuming your view is named Create and it is expecting an object of type Person.
}
```

**View**

```
@model Project.Models.Person // top of view

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SpecialSauce) // you can't submit disabled items to the server so create a HiddenField to hold the actual value for submission

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SpecialSauce, null, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" }) // the textbox on page load should contain "Ketchup" and be disabled so the user can't edit the string
```

Then, your ModelState will be valid and then you don't have to set it in the HttpPost action method.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think I am begining to realize the convention is to have a model specific to your view, and a seperate one specific to the database as in my case "special sauce" is the result of a lookup on the persons name. The tutorial i went through on MVC did not talk about this distinction.

Comment: @n00b In that case, a ViewModel would be appropriate and then look into AutoMapper for easy mapping of properties instead of having to manually write each one.

Comment: You will run into an overposting problem with this.  since you are defining specialsauce in your model, anyone can post a value to SpecialSauce using fiddler/postman/... Also disabled input items are not sent back to the server in a POST.  Use a view model.

Comment: @Fran good point about not being able to submit disabled items.  I updated my answer to reflect a HiddenFor for the submission.  I do agree with the ViewModel approach.  My answer was just based on the information I was given.

Comment: Leaving this as the selected answer, since you answered the question, but I agree in the end, I need a view model.

Comment: Hidden fields can be seen in the html source of the page so make sure never to store sensitive data there.